# How to create custom project that inherits from c# using MPF?

Tags: c#, vsx, extensibility, subtype, mpf

Using Visual Studio's Managed Package Framework, how can I inherit from C# so I can have C# property pages and C# project items? I've tried making a flavored project, but it was limited in terms of making our own custom nodes and custom file properties. When using the MPF, however, I cannot seem to obtain those C# properties that were provided with the flavored project.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a long week and a half, I was finally given a solution by an employee at Microsoft:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/bfe5d211-c626-43ff-9096-c75023a76ca5

Hope this helps everyone who has upvoted/favorited this question...